# How can I display the results of mysql_fetch_assoc in a dynamic table?

Tags: mysql, php5, ajax

I have a MySQL database with several columns and two rows of data, so far. I'm using mysql_fetch_assoc to return the data in database, but I don't know how to put it all together in a table so that I can display it in another file.

Here is the code of the file that does the process (`query.php`):

```
<?php

// Configure connection settings

$db = 'scorecard';
$db_admin = 'root';
$db_password = '********';
$tablename = 'scoreboard';

// Title

//echo "<b>DIV!</b>";

// Connect to DB

$sql = mysql_connect("localhost", $db_admin, $db_password)
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("$db", $sql);

// Fetch the data

$query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_error();

echo "<table width='100%'>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";

// Return the results, loop through them and echo

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$codcliente = $row['codcliente'];
$nombre = $row['nombre'];
$ejecutivo = $row['ejecutivo'];
$banca_as400 = $row['banca_as400'];
$banca_real = $row['banca_real'];
$ingresos = $row['ingresos'];
$ciiu = $row['ciiu'];
$division = $row['division'];
$actividad = $row['actividad'];
$riesgo_industria = $row['riesgo_industria'];
$riesgo_cliente = $row['riesgo_cliente'];
$fecha = $row['fecha'];
$analista = $row['analista'];
echo "<tr><td>$codcliente</td><td>$nombre</td><td>$ejecutivo</td><td>$banca_as400</td><td>$banca_real</td><td>$ingresos</td><td>$ciiu</td><td>$division</td><td>$actividad</td><td>$riesgo_industria</td><td>$riesgo_cliente</td><td>$fecha</td><td>$analista</td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td>$codcliente</td><td>$nombre</td><td>$ejecutivo</td><td>$banca_as400</td><td>$banca_real</td><td>$ingresos</td><td>$ciiu</td><td>$division</td><td>$actividad</td><td>$riesgo_industria</td><td>$riesgo_cliente</td><td>$fecha</td><td>$analista</td></tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
}
```

And this is the result from the page that displays the process (`index.php`):

CAN'T DISPLAY SINCE I DON'T HAVE ENOUGH REPUTATION POINTS :(

As you can see, I have a table already in place and I would like the results to fall below as additional rows, but they come out all squashed together. I've tried several mysql_fetch types, but nothing works. The query results are displayed in a JavaScript DIV that is automatically refreshed by an AJAX script from another file (`ajax.js`). If you need to see the code for `index.php` or `ajax.js`, I could provide it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you forgetting something, called `<td>`?

Try

```
<?php

// Configure connection settings

$db = 'scorecard';
$db_admin = 'root';
$db_password = '********';
$tablename = 'scoreboard';

// Title

//echo "<b>DIV!</b>";

// Connect to DB

$sql = mysql_connect("localhost", $db_admin, $db_password)
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("$db", $sql);

// Fetch the data

$query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_error();

echo "<table width='100%'>\n";

// Return the results, loop through them and echo

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<tr>'."\n";
    echo "<td>{$row['codcliente']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['nombre']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['ejecutivo']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['banca_as400']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['banca_real']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['ingresos']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['ciiu']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['division']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['actividad']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['riesgo_industria']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['riesgo_cliente']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['fecha']}</td>\n" . "<td>{$row['analista']}</td>\n";

    echo '</tr>'."\n";
}

echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

Comment: Hi @maz...I actually didn't forget, I posted a fork on my original code, sorry. I edited the question to reflect what I had before, since I can't paste it in the comment box.

Comment: it works! All I have to do now is get it to align it with the headers in the `index.php` table. Thanks!

P.S. Can you tell me what I was doing wrong? (look at updated code)

Comment: You should look up how to format tables, I put a td around each cell, and a tr around each row, whereas you just had a tr around the entire thing. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Thanks @maz, I had tried several ways to generate the table, but I had never used the `."\n"` in the rows or the `\n" .` in the cells. Don't know if that made a difference. When I did it my way, it would return the first row in the DB formatted and the second squashed together.

Comment: That is just so the code formatted more clearly (when you view the source), and isn't needed at all, the big difference were the `<td>`s surrounding each field, and the `<tr>` inside the loop.